# Does everyone have same number of sade satti?

Tags: astrology

Does every astrological sign have same number of sade satti?

If no, please share those signs with less number or less years of sade satti in a life?

Also what are the auspicious sign where a person can enjoy good luck and no money problems with good behaviour in their life?

Comment: On an average, every Rasi will have same number of sade sathi years.

Comment: I heard that acquarius has less number

Comment: I will check and get back on this.